# Shorthand for SQL query to count records by day across many tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table to validate my data across many different tables within a dataset. I use the following SQL query to do this, but is there any way to save time copying in the names of all tables within my dataset, either in the top level SELECT statement or the sub queries?

```
SELECT Date, records_table1, records_table2...

FROM

(SELECT RowDate as Date, Count(RowDate) AS records_table1 FROM [project:dataset.table1] GROUP BY Date),

(SELECT RowDate as Date, Count(RowDate) AS records_table2 FROM [project:dataset.table2] GROUP BY Date),

...
```

Comment: what are you joining table 1 and table 2 on?

Comment: RowDate - I only need to show a column for date and then a column for each table showing the number of records on each date (which comes through as record count)

Comment: ok so there is no natural join between the two tables?

Comment: See below - think this is how i would write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.records_table2 from 
(SELECT RowDate as Date, Count(RowDate) AS records_table1 FROM [project:dataset.table1] GROUP BY Date)a
full join 
(SELECT RowDate as Date, Count(RowDate) AS records_table2 FROM [project:dataset.table2] GROUP BY Date)b 
on a.[Date]=b.[Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `union all` :

```
select RowDate, sum(table1) as records_table1, sum(table2) as records_table2
from (select RowDate, 1 as table1, 0 as table2
      from [project:dataset.table1] 
      union all
      select RowDate, 0, 1
      from [project:dataset.table2] 
     ) t
group by RowDate;
```